# CSOM caml query list view lookup threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I have a list with about 15 managed metadata columns in it. Now I want to query that list using CSOM. I don't want to retrieve all the columns values so I limited the column values retrieved by using the include function. See code below

```
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
ListItemCollection items = pagesList.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items, item => item.Include(i => i["Column1"]));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

When I execute the code I get the following error *"Value does not fall within the expected range."* For the first managed metadata columns in the list, this is working fine. So looks like the list view lookup threshold is the problem.

I also tried to retrieve the same column when querying only one item and this was working fine.

```
ListItem litem =pagesList.GetItemById(1);
ctx.Load(litem, i => i["Column1"]);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

This is expected behavior if I look to the list view lookup threshold, because the following line is in the explanation of this threshold: *"This does not apply to single item operations"*. See msdn post below. 
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx#ListLibrary)

My question is, why do I have problems with the list view lookup threshold? I'm only trying to retrieve 1 managed metadatafield. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the overload that takes in a ViewFields param array:
 [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee543831.aspx)

Try the following:

```
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000, "Column1");
ListItemCollection items = pagesList.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your list contains an item, which does not have the Field "Column1"? It does not look like a treshold problem (as per default the treshold is 5000 items and i guess you didn´t set it to 1)